# Building the Graffiti CMS Source Code and Deploying Website

Tags: visual-studio, open-source, graffiticms

Can anyone provide any assistance with building the Graffiti CMS (http://graffiticms.codeplex.com) source code to have a ready to deploy web site? When I download the source and do a Visual Studio build everything builds fine.

When I look at the folder on disk of Graffiti.Web I see there are a lot of extra files that are not needed for the final deployed web site, but when I do a "Publish" there are files missing (most notably all .view files and files from the __utility folder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone the route of using a robocopy script after I do a VS build. Full details at http://graffiticms.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=79931

It seems to be working well for me so far.